# Extract substring after '@' character in Google Sheets for Tweet analysis

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, data-extraction, tweets

I am using the following formula trying to extract the substring *@sizzlegg* and *@fckoeln_en!* from column B, the problem is that I get an error when using REGEXTRACT to identify the '@' symbol.

I need it to extract anything straight after the '@' (at/tag symbol) no matter the length of the value text in column B or the length of the substring immediately after the symbol.

`=REGEXEXTRACT(B18,".*@(.*)")`

[image: Screenshot of Google Sheet rows]

Comment: Your goal is unclear. Please share a link to a sample spreadsheet with, say, 5 or 10 rows of realistic data and your *hand-entered* results of what you'd like to see a formula return for those rows, where you want the formula to return it. That will be the most efficient means of getting help. Currently, you have multiple instances of @ in a single string, and all we see is an error, which is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(@\w+)","($1)"))
```

[image]

### explantation

- first, identifiy alphanumeric characters ([a-zA-Z0-9_]) following with @ and add parentheses around => thus we will get a regular expression `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(@\w+)","($1)")`
- then, use that regular expression to extract these alphanumeric characters with `=regexextract(A1,regular expression)`

### note

if you have already parentheses `()` in A1, you have to remove them first

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\(|\)",""),REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\(|\)",""),"(@\w+)","($1)"))
```